# auto.commit.enable property not working expected

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am relatively new to this area ,i am using high level consumers and using confluent api and running through curl and postman

Using following steps :

1) Create consumer group :POST
    http://hostname/consumers/test

```
{
"name": "offset_test_instance4", 
"format": "json", 
"auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
"auto.commit.enable": "false"
}
```

2)  Assign the partitions using the below api : POST
    http://hostname/consumers/test/instances/offset_test_instance4/assignments

```
{
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "ids_mps_channel_permissions",
      "partition": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

3)  Reading the content: GET
    http://hostname/consumers/test/instances/offset_test_instance4/records?timeout=5000&max_bytes=16777216

i am Getting responses from above get request.

But when i am hitting again its giving me new offset though i have not committed any offset still offsets is keep on increasing.

Since i have disabled the auto commit property, so my understanding was it won't commit the offset until i commit it manually.

Please advice if i am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior. You don't have to commit an offset in order to get new messages. These are independent things. You might get 50 messages first and then commit your offset.

Comment: I don't understand the answer sorry! Why is offset increased automatically here even if new offset is not being committed manually and the "auto.commit.enable" is set to "false"?

Comment: There are two types of offsets. There are the offsets that are part of every message stored in the commit log and they go up by 1 for each message published and written to the partition. Then separately each consumer can commit (to a separate topic) their own offset which represents their last successfully processed message. If you read 5 new messages they will each have 5 message offsets (for example 1,2,3,4,5) that is expected even if you have only committed offset 1.